# PHP and use of the Num_Of_Rows() function?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Below is some PHP code that i have written, the problem occurs when it gets to the use of the num_of_rows(), it just does not seem to work and i cant figure out why?

```
<?php
try
{
    $divMon_ID = array();
    $divMon_Position = array();
    $divMon_Width = array();
    $divMon_Div = array();

    $db = new PDO('sqlite:db/EVENTS.sqlite');
    $result_mon = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Monday');
    $totalRows = mysql_num_rows($result_mon);
    //for($counter=1; $counter<=10; $counter+=1)
    //{

        //<div id="event_1" style="position:absolute; left: 0px; top:-39px; width:100px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:small; border:2px blue solid; height:93px">
        //$divMon_ID[]=$row['Id'];
        //$divMon_Position[]=$row['Origin'];
        //$divMon_P[]=$row['Position'];
    //}
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    print 'Exception : '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

?>

I know that it is the "$totalRows = mysql_num_rows($result_mon);" statement because when i then comment it out, the page can load.

Am i using the function in the wrong way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use mysql_num_rows with pdo. You have to use [rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Answer (score 1):

Mysql_num_rows would work if you used mysql_connect, and other mysql_* functions. As you are using PDO, you have to use PDO's methods, like [rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Answer (score 0):

You've created a PDO object connecting to an SQLite database. Why should a MySQL function know how to deal with any of that?

The `query` method returns an object of type `PDOStatement`, which has a [`rowCount`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) method. Use that:

```
$totalRows = $result_mon->rowCount();
```

That is, if you even need to know the total number of rows before you process them. If *all* you need to know is the number of rows in the table, consider using the `COUNT` SQL function instead: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Monday`.